# Sumif with exclusion criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet with a list of 150 names on it, plus phone times and down time. Spreadsheets name is All Names. I have another sheet named Exclude with 30 of those names. I need a formula that will add all the phone times in column B, but excluding the 30 names on Exclude.

Comment: Simplest option: in your Exclude sheet, add a helper column with SUMIFS formulas which picks up all matching amounts for each of those names. Then just take the total sum, - the sum of amounts from your Exclude sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B150)-SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B1:B150,A1:A150,'All Names'!A1:'All Names'!A30))
```